How to understand the sentence structure of It marked a shift the country…

It marked a shift the country which has long acknowledged the science of the climate crisis, but has focused its environmental cleanup efforts on issues such as air pollution – rather than severe but relatively rare floods and droughts.

From an article 
The “which” introduces a relative clause to tell us more about the country, which, I thought, makes the whole sentence incomplete(It marked a shift the country(some more descriptions). So how can I understand the structure of the sentence?

I don't understand it either - it must be a typo. "A shift in the country", perhaps?

It should say "It marked a shift in a country which has long acknowledged..." However, if China is a major focus for this author, referring to them as "a country" seems dismissive.   It's "the country!".

@Sam - I do not agree. It marked a shift in the country [which is the one under discussion].

@MichaelHarvey, not sure I agree.  With "the" in place, the following clause takes on another meaning. That causes China to be "the country" which something.   China is the country which takes human rights the most seriously.   It singles them out by using the definite article.   Well, that could go either way, but it's a possible interpretation.

@Sam -  China is the country which takes human rights the most seriously We could have an argument about whether that is true, but not here. However I stand by my assertion that 'the country' is correct in the piece quoted in the OP. I don;t see the definite artice 'singling out China in the OP's sentence. It could in others, of course.

What does it actually say if the OP's transcription is incorrect? I cannot see the original article.

@TimR - it's in the UK Guardian, is by 'Amy Hawkins Senior China correspondent' and contains the typo as quoted, as of right now https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/dec/24/we-need-to-be-prepared-china-adapts-to-era-of-extreme-flooding

@TimR - Don't tell me the Donald is blocking the Guardian already?

@TimR - by the way, happy holidays! And best wishes for 2025!

@MichaelHarvey Back at you, Michael :-)

There is a country which has long acknowledged the science of the climate crisis.
This country has focused its environmental cleanup efforts on air pollution, not on severe but relatively rare (infrequent? if so, how is the frequency being measured? ) floods and droughts.
Something has marked a shift in the way this country approaches the climate crisis.
Presumably (lacking context) the country is now focusing on the severe but not constant events that result from constant, ongoing conditions such as air pollution.
